# How to export Leaflet map to tiff image using react?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, tiff, react-leaflet, geotiff

i'm trying to create geotiff/tiff file from leaflet-map. i already check on any plugin that can export map to image like leaflet.print, leaflet-easyprint, leaflet-image, leaflet.browser.print. but they cant give me tiff file output. and also i find [leaflet.export](https://github.com/Flexberry/Leaflet.Export), but i dont know how to use it on my code. is there any way to export leaflet-map to tiff image by using specific latitude and longitude(if it possible) or maybe export the whole map area on the screen. here my code on react :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Grid, Input, Form, Icon } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import {
  Map,
  TileLayer,
  FeatureGroup,
  ZoomControl,
} from 'react-leaflet';
import L from 'leaflet';

class Home extends Component {

  state = {
    inputLat: -6.3678159,
    inputLong: 106.8345207,
  };

  handleDownloadGeoTiff = async () => {
    // console.log('handle download geoTiff');
  };

render() {
   return (
      <Grid>
        <Grid.Row className='containerRowHome' columns={1}>
          <Grid.Column className='colMaps' width={16}>
            <Map
              className='map'
              center={[this.state.inputLat, this.state.inputLong]}
              zoom={this.props.currentZoom}
              maxZoom={20}
              attributionControl={true}
              zoomControl={false}
              doubleClickZoom={true}
              scrollWheelZoom={true}
              dragging={true}
              animate={true}
              easeLinearity={0.35}
              preferCanvas={true}
            >
              <TileLayer
                url='https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.png'
                attribution='&copy; <a href="Esri &mdash">Esri, i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye, Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the GIS User Community</a> contributors'
                maxNativeZoom={19}
                maxZoom={25}
              />
              <ZoomControl position='topright' />
            </Map>
            <Icon
              className='validDownload'
              onClick={this.handleDownloadGeoTiff}
              name='download'
              inverted
              circular
              link
            />
          </Grid.Column>
        </Grid.Row>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}

export default(Home);
```